# Express - handling json response

Tags: node.js, express

I have two node servers (A + B) and both use Expressjs.

From one I use Request (https://github.com/mikeal/request) to make a GET request to the other:

```
//A server
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  request('http://localhost:8080/api/' + req.params.id, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  })
});
```

and the other is:

```
//B server
app.get('/api/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.json(200, {url: "http://www.google.co.uk"});  
});
```

As you can see, A is making a request to B and B returns a json result. However, I'm not sure how to deal with the response in A. `console.log(body)` prints the complete json but how can I access the url sent from B?

I have tried `body.url` but no luck

Comment: try JSON.parse on the result, prior to accessing it like an object.

Comment: that's done the trick - put it as an answer if you like and I will tick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSON` result is a string. You must first parse it via `JSON.parse`, prior to accessing it like an object:

```
var url = JSON.parse(body).url;
```